# Average All Numbers in Column Across Separate Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find the average of all numbers in a particular column across separate sheets.

For example, let's say each table is a sheet

Sheet 1 -

| ID | Cost | Customer Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 10 | Small |
| 0002 | 15 | Large |

Sheet 2 -

| ID | Cost | Customer Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0003 | 20 | Small |
| 0004 | 25 | Large |

Sheet 3 -

| ID | Cost | Customer Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0005 | 30 | Small |
| 0006 | 35 | Large |

I want to create a formula that takes all raw numbers in the cost columns and finds the average.

I also want to incorporate `IFERROR` that shows `N/A` if for whatever reason all cells in cost column are blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT (following your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75585821/average-all-numbers-in-column-across-separate-sheets/75586381?noredirect=1#comment133354666_75586381))**
You can also use:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({Sheet1!B2:C;Sheet2!B2:C;Sheet3!B2:C},
            "select Col2, avg(Col1) 
             where Col2 is not null 
             group by Col2 label avg(Col1) '' "),
       "no values")
```

You mention:

> I also want to incorporate IFERROR that shows "N/A" if for whatever
> reason all cells in cost column are blank.

Please try the following

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE({Sheet1!B2:B;Sheet2!B2:B;Sheet3!B2:B}),
        "no values")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

Comment: This worked! I made an edit to the posting. How would I create a formula that only considered large customers and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
=AVERAGE({Sheet1!B2:B;Sheet2!B2:B;Sheet3!B2:B})
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error - "#DIV/0" "Error Evaluation of function AVERAGE caused a divide by zero error" Is there a way to account for blanks?

Comment: Wrap everything in IFERROR `=IFERROR(the formula,what you want to say when there are no values)`

Comment: Thanks! How would I create a formula that only considered large customers and vice versa? I made an edit to the tables.

Comment: You'll be able to do it with FILTER or AVERAGEIF. Please mark answers as accepted and/or upvoted, and upload a new specific question

Comment: Will do! Would you be able to provide an example of how to write the formula either incorporating FILTER or AVERAGEIF?